# Force foreground an application from the background

Tags: android, ios, iphone, ionic-framework

I'm developing viber like application using the ionic framework.
I want my app to be able to receive calls even when its on the background, just like whatsapp, the incoming call screen will pop up even if whatsapp is on the background or even when there is no instance of it at all.

I wasn't able to find anything about it.

Comment: Background support is very limited indeed e with cordova. Its not really its main point of intended use. You need to remember you are running a webview. For example on android I know you need some sort of background service to run it. There is a plugin that I have come across https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/tree/1210563 for this on android.  IOS I am yet to find but you should be able to write a plugin. It might be a painful experience doe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no other way to achive this, then using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). Although there may be other services that do the same.

When using GCM, your app will be notified with a notification even if it is not running.

But be careful! As your using Ionic, you will most likely rely on a cordova plugin to receive the notifications that are pushed to your device via GCM.

It depends on the chosen plugin how it handles the incoming notification.